# SDL_TTF Wrapping text with background color

Tags: sdl-2

I am trying to change the background color of the text to black so it is easier to read. I do want the text to wrap though but when I use TTF_RenderText_Blended_Wrapped I have no option to change the background color. If I use TTF_RenderText_Shaded I can set the background color but can't wrap text. Anybody know a way of doing this?

```
 Scene1::fsurface = TTF_RenderText_Blended_Wrapped(Scene1::font, imu, Scene1::fcolor, 300);
 // Scene1::fsurface = TTF_RenderText_Shaded(Scene1::font, imu, Scene1::fcolor,Scene1::bcolor);
```

Comment: Seems odd that the function `TTF_RenderTextBlended_Wrapped()` is not on their docs, https://www.libsdl.org/projects/SDL_ttf/docs/SDL_ttf.html#SEC51